# D3: Formatting tick value. To show B (Billion) instead of G (Giga)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to format Y-axis data in D3 Line chart. It's about world population so that is quite large.

I am currently using below code, which is showing "G" instead of "B".

```
d3.format("s")
```

I researched and found that here "G" stands of Giga, is there a way to change it to B which denotes Billion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you like the formatting of SI-prefix, but not the actual prefix, just swap it out with a simple `.replace`:

```js
var f = d3.format("0.2s");

document.write(
  f(1e9).replace(/G/,"B")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to override the library globally, but you want to use your "B" function around the place the same way as d3.format:

```
import { format } from 'd3-format';
export const formatBillions = fs => s => format(fs)(s).replace(/G/, "B");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply Mark's Answer Globally, I used the following

```
fcopy = d3.format;
function myFormat(){ 
         function_ret = fcopy.apply(d3, arguments) 
         return (function(args){return function (){ 
                return args.apply(d3, arguments).replace(/G/, "B");
         }})(function_ret) 
} 
d3.format = myFormat;
```

I had the same problem with [Superset](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/), I added this in the static/dashboard file.

Comment: hi, could u please show me the way u apply this for the whole project?

Answer (score 1):

For those needing this with `plotly.js` (which uses d3 under the hood), you can provide the `exponentformat` to the axis, as well as optional `tickprefix`, should you want tick formats to be `$1B` not `$1G`) ([see types for details of values `exponentformat` accepts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/43230d1902f5682147845ec995890a032bd1a3d5/types/plotly.js/index.d.ts#L692)):

```js
import { Layout } from "plotly.js";

const layout: Partial<Layout> = {
  xaxis: {
    ... // your other layout values
    tickprefix: "$", // use manual prefix as we can't use `tickformat` w/ `exponentformat`
    exponentformat: "B", // use billions not giga
  },
}
```