# B (billions) instead of G (giga) in python plotly customdata [SI prefix d3]

Tags: python, d3.js, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I have gone through [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/custom-si-unit-prefixes/29739), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774677/d3-formatting-tick-value-to-show-b-billion-instead-of-g-giga) and some other similar posts. They all give the solution in javascript which I am unable to port to python. Help would be appreciated.

When I pass a value to `customdata` which is big enough to be a billion, it shows the sign as G (for giga) rather than B, whereas plotly defaults to B, the comparison can be seen in the image. Is there a way to use B instead of G?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[500,3000,50000,100000,7000000,80000000,400000000,9000000000]})
more_data = [100,3000,50000,600000,2000000,90000000,500000000,3000000000]

fig = px.line(df, log_y=True)
fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers',
                  customdata=more_data,
                  hovertemplate='%{y}<br>%{customdata:,.1s}')
```

Comment: Hi, did you check this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1222)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to be the most elegant solution ever but it fixes your problem. If you look carefully your plot you have a problem on index 1 too where the overdata is `3000<br>3k`.

So I'm actually writing hover data explicitly. We will need the function `human_format` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846841/4819376).

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [500,3000,50000,100000,7000000,80000000,400_000_000,9_000_000_000],
                  'more_data': [100,3000,50000,600000,2000000,90000000,500000000,3_000_000_000]})
```

## Write hoverdata

```py
def human_format(num):
    num = float('{:.3g}'.format(num))
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.0
    return '{}{}'.format('{:f}'.format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), 
                         ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'][magnitude])

df["hover_data"] = df.apply(lambda r: 
    f"{human_format(r['x'])}<br>{human_format(r['more_data'])}",
                            axis=1)
```

## Plot

```py
fig = px.line(df, 
              y="x", log_y=True)
fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers',
                  customdata=df['hover_data'],
                  hovertemplate='%{customdata}')
```

Comment: That is ingenious!! Thank you. I ended up making `hover_data` only include the info for edited column `more_data` and then did the addition of other columns with `<br>` in the `hovertemplate` instead.